# using OR in sql join is slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a scenario as below.

Employee table

```
EmpId X_Id  Flag
--------------------------------
1      123     0
```

Dept table

```
DeptId D.Name X_Id  Flag
----------------------------------------------
1        a     123    0
2        b     123    1
```

i need to write a query that fetches the rows based on the flag. ie., if flag is 0 in EmpTable, then get only rows which have flag as 0 and if flag is set to 1 in EmpTable, get all rows (with flag as 0 and 1). To achieve this, i have written the below query

```
SELECT E.EmpId, E.X_Id, D.Did, D.Dname
FROM EmpTable E INNER JOIN DeptTable D
ON E.X_Id = D.X_Id
AND (D.Flag = 0 or D.Flag = E.Flag)
```

the above query returns correct rows, but as I see it, using OR is not a good idea. the query is slow.
Any alternatives to achieve the same with optimal performance??

Comment: Is the flag a boolean, because if so then do you even need the condition at all? As it stands you are always returning when the Dept.Flag is 0 so the join only comes into play if the Employee.Flag is 1 in which case you'd add those conditionally

Answer (score 2):

The only obvious alternative is

```
SELECT E.EmpId,
       E.X_Id,
       D.Did,
       D.Dname
FROM   EmpTable E
       INNER JOIN DeptTable D
         ON E.X_Id = D.X_Id
            AND D.Flag = E.Flag
UNION
SELECT E.EmpId,
       E.X_Id,
       D.Did,
       D.Dname
FROM   EmpTable E
       INNER JOIN DeptTable D
         ON E.X_Id = D.X_Id
            AND D.Flag = 0
```

Sometimes rewriting `OR` as `UNION` can help performance. If that doesn't help you would need to look at the execution plan to see if you are missing any required indexes for example.

Answer (score 0):

A reach but maybe worth a try.
Sometimes a join settles on one index.
If you split it up then sometimes it will use separate indexes.
Look at the query plan.

```
SELECT E.EmpId, E.X_Id, D.Did, D.Dname
FROM EmpTable E 
JOIN DeptTable D1
  ON E.X_Id = D1.X_Id 
JOIN DeptTable D2
  ON D2.Flag = E.Flag
  OR D2.Flag = 0

SELECT E.EmpId, E.X_Id, D.Did, D.Dname
FROM EmpTable E 
JOIN DeptTable D1
  ON E.X_Id = D1.X_Id 
WHERE D2.Flag = E.Flag
   OR D2.Flag = 0
```